# How to use jbuilder to render a view partial to a variable in the controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

When certain actions are performed, I am sending a json message to the client using web sockets. I like to be able to use view helpers in the jbuilder file so that I can nicely format json data.

How would one go about getting view-ready json into a variable in the controller? The best I have come up with is to use `render_to_string`, which works, but returns a `String`, so I then have to do `JSON.parse`, which is a lot of wasted converting, right?

So I have this:

```
msg = JSON.parse(render_to_string('show'))
```

which renders `show.json.jbuilder` into json and then returns it as a string, which is then parsed back into json.

It works, but it feels so wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled around for hours, and also doing things that are just wrong. I have two horrible hacks. First problem I had was trying to use jbuilder to construct json to be stored in a payload that was not in a MVC context, but in a sidekiq worker. Luckily, I only needed one representation so I essentially rebuilt the template in `user.rb` Redacted example shown below.

```
def to_builder
  Jbuilder.new do |user|
    user.external_id id
    user.username username
    user.full_name full_name
  end
end
```

And then used

```
to_user_hash = {}
to_user_hash["user"] = JSON.parse(user.to_builder.target!)
```

to store the json, incredibly idiotic.

Now even more insane, when I was using `active_model_serializers` I was using a sidekiq worker to render a live activities page via websockets and did the following.

```
class ActivityBroadcasterWorker < ApplicationWorker
  sidekiq_options queue: :low, retry: true, backtrace: true

  def perform(activity_id)
    view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)
    view.class_eval("include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers")
    view.extend ApplicationHelper

    if activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_by_id(activity_id)
      template = view.render_activity(activity)
      ActionCable.server.broadcast('activity_channel', message: template)
    end
  end
end
```

Have you found any better solution to simply tell jbuilder here is my resource, and i want to render this view, or this view partial?